# Remove Volume Information lines from dir command using java

Tags: java, groovy

I get this output from `dir /a C:\Information\DataTransformation\externLibs\system`

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1878-D614

 Directory of C:\Information\DataTransformation\externLibs\system

08/23/2011  09:52 PM    &lt;DIR&gt;          .
08/23/2011  09:52 PM    &lt;DIR&gt;          ..
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           196,608 AFPtoXML_DP.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            13,259 ASN1toXSDRunner.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM    &lt;DIR&gt;          birt
08/23/2011  09:52 PM             8,192 CM_CreateUUID.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            19,456 EdifactValidation.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            60,145 EDIValidator.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            20,159 Excel2007ToDataXml.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           217,088 ExcelToHtml.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           192,512 ExcelToTxt.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           541,646 ExcelToXml.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            23,401 ExcelToXmlDataOnly.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            10,032 ExcelToXml_03_07_10.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM             8,192 guid_transformer.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM             9,216 hebAsciiBidiKH.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            40,960 hebAsciiBidiMoz.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM    &lt;DIR&gt;          HIPAAValidation
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            21,921 HIPAAValidation.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM             1,613 IBANValidator.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM             4,641 loader.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            24,576 MSMQ.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            24,576 MSMQOutput.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            28,672 ODBC.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           209,563 OfficeToXml.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            17,408 PdfFormToXml_1_00_DP.dll
08/23/2011  09:53 PM    &lt;DIR&gt;          PDFLanguages
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           286,720 PdfToTxt2_3_02_07_DP.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           409,600 PdfToTxt_2_02.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           528,384 PdfToTxt_3_00_DP.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           634,880 PdfToTxt_3_02_DP.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM    &lt;DIR&gt;          poi
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            24,576 PowerpointToHTML.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            13,643 PptToXml.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM             1,487 Regex1_4.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            29,696 RtfToTxt_DP.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           217,088 WordToHtml.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           188,416 WordToRtf.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           188,416 WordToTxt.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           305,428 WordToXml.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            73,728 WpToTxt_DP.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM            19,456 X12EDIValidation.dll
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           927,669 xercesImpl.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           115,701 xercesSamples.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           123,705 xml-apis.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           123,705 xmlParserAPIs.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM             8,786 XmlToBirtPP.jar
08/23/2011  09:52 PM           671,744 XpdfText.dll
          42 File(s)      6,586,664 bytes
           6 Dir(s)  15,978,725,376 bytes free
```

I want to remove the below lines from output

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1878-D614

 Directory of C:\Information\DataTransformation\externLibs\system
```

My Code

```
def externalLibrarySystem(csm,pluginOutputs)
{
String rs = (String)pluginOutputs.get("ExternalLibrarySystem")
String temp=rs

csm.externalLibrarySystem(rs)
{
    "${rs}"
}
}
```

**Note: temp has the dir output**

Comment: @Arne: How can I remove `Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1878-D614

 Directory of C:\Information\DataTransformation\externLibs\system` from `temp` string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you use the Scanner class.
Copy line for line to a StringBuilder. Have a int counter and don't append the first 5 lines.

```
String rs = (String)pluginOutputs.get("ExternalLibrarySystem");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(rs);
  int cnt = 0;
  while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
   if(cnt>4){
      sb.append(sc.nextLine()+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
   }
   cnt++;
  }
String temp = sb.toString();
```